# OpenCV camera calibration - how to conglomerate calibration results from multiple images into one set of calibration parameters?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I'm performing camera calibration with OpenCV in Python for the first time.  I've performed camera calibration with other vision packages before so I'm familiar with the process.  So far I've followed this tutorial https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html which was very helpful.

If I use the example chess board pattern calibration images that OpenCV provides from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/data, `left01.jpg` through `left14.jpg` the results for the above tutorial for each image are good.

At the end, following the above tutoiral, I'm calling `initUndistortRectifyMap`, then `remap`.  The inputs to `initUndistortRectifyMap` are `cameraMatrix`, `distCoeffs`, and `newCameraMatrix`.  In the above tutorial these 3 variables are calculated separately for each image `left01.jpg` through `left14.jpg` and then applied to each image `left01.jpg` through `left14.jpg` individually.

For actual camera calibration, I'm under the impression that I would need to calibrate on many images (probably 50+ for production grade results).  Then when the program is starting I would load `cameraMatrix`, `distCoeffs`, and `newCameraMatrix` from some type of config file, call `initUndistortRectifyMap` to get `map1` and `map2`, then each time a new image is obtained call `remap`.

My question is, what is the standard way to conglomerate the values for `cameraMatrix`, `distCoeffs`, and `newCameraMatrix` from multiple images into one setting for each of these 3 data structures?  Do I simply cache the results for `cameraMatrix`, `distCoeffs`, and `newCameraMatrix` each in some type of variable while going through the 50+ images, then average each of the values for each across the 50?  This seems to be the obvious way to do it, but I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it, or if a more sophisticated method is necessary or would be beneficial.

To make my question more concrete, here is some example output from the above tutorial, I just changed the variable names slightly and added some print statements.  I'm only showing 3 results for brevity:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
imageFileName = left04.jpg
cameraMatrix = [[515.51273861   0.         341.23697124]
 [  0.         515.48750138 234.27066711]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
distCoeffs = [[-2.04120057e-01 -1.03446509e+00  2.31949959e-03 -2.67680902e-03
   5.40565638e+00]]
newCameraMatrix = [[555.35675049   0.         320.32811234]
 [  0.         496.67471313 235.04880727]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
-----------------------------------------------------
imageFileName = left03.jpg
cameraMatrix = [[538.77944522   0.         338.46560887]
 [  0.         537.75253881 229.53022945]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
distCoeffs = [[-0.31629594  0.33427194  0.00416541 -0.00153091 -0.51731552]]
newCameraMatrix = [[396.84649658   0.         345.60440271]
 [  0.         419.1550293  223.4569963 ]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
-----------------------------------------------------
imageFileName = left14.jpg
cameraMatrix = [[530.89655954   0.         338.25309591]
 [  0.         531.05459141 231.03714151]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
distCoeffs = [[-0.29627459  0.21262508  0.00140653 -0.0004961  -0.25326159]]
newCameraMatrix = [[315.26034546   0.         309.90506623]
 [  0.         324.63635254 200.73965265]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
```

To get the final `cameraMatrix`, `distCoeffs`, and `newCameraMatrix`, for example for `cameraMatrix` would you average the `515.51273861`, `538.77944522`, and `530.89655954` to get the 1st `cameraMatrix`, average `341.23697124`, `338.46560887`, and `338.25309591` to get the 3rd `cameraMatrix` number, etc. for each number within each of these data structures?  Again I realize for any production I would be using way more than 3 images.

Comment: Usually you would use an optimization method called bundle adjustment "simultaneously refining the 3D coordinates describing the scene geometry, the parameters of the relative motion, and the optical characteristics of the camera(s) employed to acquire the images, according to an optimality criterion involving the corresponding image projections of all points" (wikipedia.com). There are various open-source bundle adjustment tools like e.g. bundler or ceres-solver

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't want to call several times the calibration function. You want to call the calibration process once, and find the best parameter optimization that fit many images. Therefore, you only get one camera matrix/dist coef, so you don't have to average. More precisely, if you are using:
`ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)`
You have to get as many lines in objpoints and imgpoints as you have images. From your question, I assume that you have only one pair of objpoints / imgpoints.

The purpose of "newCameraMatrix" is to define the area to visible after resampling. If you want to see all of your image pixels and have black areas where it's not defined (because of the lens deformation for example), or if you want to crop the image so that all pixels contain some image data after the remap. Therefore it is recommended to store the cameramatrix, and calculate the newcameramatrix in your production program, so that you can interact easily with the alpha parameter. It is better to store the alpha than the modified camera matrix.
I hope this replies to your question!